# Possible to save form "field by field" as soon as a user changes a field instead of pushing a save button at the end of the form?

Tags: 7, forms

Instead of pushing a save button, I would like to save user input as sooon as a field is changed. Similar to how mobile apps works. Is this possible in Drupal?

Comment: I doubt it if drupal has a out of the box solution for this but you can use ajax as you would normally do on any other website to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Autosave](https://www.drupal.org/project/autosave) module for node edit forms for exactly this use case.